# Virtual router for Android?

Tags: wi-fi, networking, router

I am aware that an Android phone plays a virtual router via the "hotspot" feature. I also realized that when an Android phone is tethered via USB for an internet connection, the machine that is tethered gets a new subnet different from that of a machine connected via a hotspot.

I have created a network drive on my Ubuntu Mate machine. It is connected via "USB-Tethered" on my Android phone (subscribed to unlimited internet).

Meanwhile, when I connect my relative's laptop (to the "hotspot") of my Android phone, they get a different subnet. As a result, the gadgets that are hotspotted cannot connect to the shared folder I created in the Ubuntu machine (which is connected to the same Android phone yet connected under a different subnet).

My problem is, how can I adjust the hotspot so that it broadcasts the same subnet the same with the subnet on the tethered machine?

Any solution is welcome!

Comment: You can bridge both subnets on Android device. Or manually create Wi-Fi hotspot and USB tethering network using same subnet. Both options require a rooted phone and familiarity with Linux networking.